# Remove multiple nodes and make the XML relational

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <IDATA>
   <RDATA>
    <TMSG xmlns:UDF="TUDF">
     <DOC RID="21ca3c51-21b8-2196-8bd6-e046365c19c8-00000020" DOCKEY="16ca3c51-21b8-4496-8bd6-e046365c19c8-0000acfe:00000018" DOCTYPE="R" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Accounting DOC View">
      <IDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
       <IDS>-1</IDS>
      </IDS.LIST>
      <DATE>20210401</DATE>
      <NARRATION>NARR1</NARRATION>
      <PARTYLDGNAME>Party1</PARTYLDGNAME>
      <DOCTYPENAME>R</DOCTYPENAME>
      <DOCNUMBER>1</DOCNUMBER>
     <DOCKEY>1</DOCKEY>
      <DTL.LIST>
       <IDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
        <IDS>-1</IDS>
       </IDS.LIST>
       <LDGNAME>Party1</LDGNAME>
       <AMOUNT>12345.00</AMOUNT>
       <VATEXPAMOUNT>100.00</VATEXPAMOUNT>
       <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
       <BA.LIST>       </BA.LIST>
      </DTL.LIST>
      <DTL.LIST>
       <IDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
        <IDS>-1</IDS>
       </IDS.LIST>
       <LDGNAME>Bank1</LDGNAME>
       <AMOUNT>-12345.00</AMOUNT>
       <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
       <BA.LIST>
        <DATE>20210401</DATE>
        <INSTRUMENTDATE>20210401</INSTRUMENTDATE>
        <NAME>e0d8881e-f228-4a66-8a00-717e11eee657</NAME>
        <TRANSACTIONTYPE>Inter Bank Transfer</TRANSACTIONTYPE>
        <PAYMENTFAVOURING>PARTY4</PAYMENTFAVOURING>
        <AMOUNT>-12345.00</AMOUNT>
       </BA.LIST>
      </DTL.LIST>
      <PAYROLLMODEOFPAYMENT.LIST>      </PAYROLLMODEOFPAYMENT.LIST>
      <ATTDRECORDS.LIST>      </ATTDRECORDS.LIST>
      <GSTEWAYCONSIGNORADDRESS.LIST>      </GSTEWAYCONSIGNORADDRESS.LIST>
      <GSTEWAYCONSIGNEEADDRESS.LIST>      </GSTEWAYCONSIGNEEADDRESS.LIST>
      <TEMPGSTRATEDETAILS.LIST>      </TEMPGSTRATEDETAILS.LIST>
     </DOC>
    </TMSG>
    <TMSG xmlns:UDF="TUDF">
     <DOC RID="21ca3c51-21b8-2196-8bd6-e046365c19c8-00000053" DOCKEY="16ca3c51-21b8-4496-8bd6-e046365c19c8-0000acfe:00000020" DOCTYPE="P" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Accounting DOC View">
      <IDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
       <IDS>-1</IDS>
      </IDS.LIST>
      <DATE>20210401</DATE>
      <NARRATION>NARR2</NARRATION>
      <PARTYLDGNAME>Cash</PARTYLDGNAME>
      <DOCTYPENAME>P</DOCTYPENAME>
      <DOCNUMBER>1</DOCNUMBER>
      <DOCKEY>2</DOCKEY>
      <DTL.LIST>
       <IDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
        <IDS>-1</IDS>
       </IDS.LIST>
       <LDGNAME>Repair and Maintance</LDGNAME>
       <GSTCLASS/>
       <AMOUNT>-321.00</AMOUNT>
       <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
       <BA.LIST>       </BA.LIST>
      </DTL.LIST>
      <DTL.LIST>
       <IDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
        <IDS>-1</IDS>
       </IDS.LIST>
       <LDGNAME>Cash</LDGNAME>
       <GSTCLASS/>
       <AMOUNT>321.00</AMOUNT>
       <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
       <BA.LIST>       </BA.LIST>
      </DTL.LIST>
      <PAYROLLMODEOFPAYMENT.LIST>      </PAYROLLMODEOFPAYMENT.LIST>
      <ATTDRECORDS.LIST>      </ATTDRECORDS.LIST>
      <GSTEWAYCONSIGNORADDRESS.LIST>      </GSTEWAYCONSIGNORADDRESS.LIST>
      <GSTEWAYCONSIGNEEADDRESS.LIST>      </GSTEWAYCONSIGNEEADDRESS.LIST>
      <TEMPGSTRATEDETAILS.LIST>      </TEMPGSTRATEDETAILS.LIST>
     </DOC>
    </TMSG>
   </RDATA>
  </IDATA>
 </BODY>
</HEAD>
```

I need to accomplish the following

1. Eliminate all IDS.LIST elements and its child elements.
2. Remove "." from the names of all other elements.
3. Need to add DOCKEY element along with its value to DTL.LIST AND BA.LIST (if it has child elements)

I started with below XSL to first remove ALL the IDS.LIST element, but I am stuck as it doesn't remove if I add the 2nd item in the except list

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="TMSG">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="* except (IDS.LIST,DTL.LIST)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am new to XSLT.

Comment: Try to simplify the problem. No-one wants to scroll through hundreds of lines of upper-case element names to find the thing you're talking about, and the problem would surely be exactly the same if most of them were removed.

Comment: Edited the input XML as suggested by Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- Eliminate all IDS.LIST elements and its child elements. -->
  <xsl:template match="IDS.LIST" priority="2"/>
  
  <!-- Remove "." from the names of all other elements. -->
  <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(.),'.')]" priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(.),'.','')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Need to add DOCKEY element along with its value to DTL.LIST AND BA.LIST (if it has child elements) -->
  <xsl:template match="DTL.LIST[node()] | BA.LIST[node()]" priority="2">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(.),'.','')}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="../DOCKEY | ../../DOCKEY"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFD9utw/2

Comment: The IDS.LIST entire node is still present which should have been removed.  Only "." has got removed from it instead.

Comment: From your above XSL, certainly I could learn the technique on how the other issues were solved.

Comment: @Learner I have edited my answer, it should work as requested now.

Comment: Just for my learning, why was my approach of  <xsl:copy-of select="* except (IDS.LIST)"/> didn't remove IDS.LIST under DTL.LIST node?  Any clue?  BTW, the XSL you have pasted works, but it leaves a blank line in that position.  Thanks for showing the approach.

Comment: Because IDS.LIST is not a child of TMSG. With your code you are in the context of a TMSG node and you copy its children. IDS.LIST is not a child of TMSG so it is not taken care of by the 'except' statement.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to clarify and all your efforts.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to get an additional element added that will have a running sequence number by name UDTLID in DTL.LIST and in BA.LIST by name UBAID which should get reset when the parent change.  In the case of BA.LIST it should have one more element with UDTLID of its parent.  If I need to create this as a new question, do let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Learner Open a new question in the XSLT section for your new requirement.

Comment: I have created a new question as suggested - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647560/udf-issue-and-addition-of-element-with-running-sequence-number-in-xml-using-xslt